# Restricting Regular expression up to certain limit using double values

Tags: regex, preg-match, regular-language

> I have been facing an issue of restricting double values upto certain
>   limit. But my regular expression does not matches the expected
>   result.Kindly guide me how to rectify it.

**Regular Expression**

```
^[0-1]?([0-5]{1,2})?(\.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Values should pass the condition ranges from range 00.00 to 15.99
```

**Failure Scenarios**

```
6.12
7.12
8.21
9.21
```

Comment: *Values should pass the condition ranges from range 00.00 to 15.99*?. Your failure cases and your expected result are opposite of each  other

Comment: @TheLostMind: I was also trying on the scenarios.It should also need to be passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work : `^(1[0-5]|0[0-9]|[0-9])(?:\.([0-9]{1,2}))$`
You can tweak the number of fractional numbers by changing the {1,2} to the min and max you want. You will get $0 for the full match, $1 is the integer part and $2 is the decimal part.

See example here : https://regex101.com/r/XC1lff/7

Comment: FYI: `0[0-9]|[0-9]` can be shrunk into `0?[0-9]` and the `(?:...)` is redundant as it contains no alterantive.

Comment: @Foxtrot Romeo: It should not pass 0.00 .. Values should start from 0.01.Can u provide me regex on it

Answer (score 2):

To match numbers from `0` to `15` with an optional leading zero and an obligatory 1 or 2 digit fractional part, you may use

```
^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-5])\.[0-9]{1,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0m6Wur/5)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-5])` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `0?[0-9]` - *an optional* `0` followed with 1 single digit
  - `|` - or
  - `1[0-5]` - `10` to `15` (`1` followed with 1 digit from `0` to `5`)
- `\.` - a dot
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - string end (may be replaced with `\z` to match the very end of string).

Comment: @ruakh - So the OP wants values between 00.00 and 15.99 to be considered *invalid*?

Comment: @ruakh: I need the expected one which u were explained.U have got my point

Comment: I was offline, sorry. I updated the answer - is it what you expect? See https://regex101.com/r/0m6Wur/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Its ok ya.. Thanks for your reponse it matches my failure scenarios. But its still matching integer values(1,2,3,4..).Still some modification needed

Comment: Ok, so the fractional part is obligatory.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: ya i need fractional with matching scenarios

Comment: Well, you did not mention that the number of digits in the fractional part can be 1 or 2. I updated the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: thanks ya.. it should not pass condition of 0.00, but i have not mentioned before sorry for late reply. Can u kindly help me  in the scenario of passing this condition

Comment: Use `^(?!0+\.0+$)(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-5])\.[0-9]{1,2}$`